# How to create a binary variable in R?

Tags: r, binary

I want to assign 1 to the one that contains name and 0 to the missing one.
I tried to use ifelse, but can not get it running. Thanks for your help.

```
Individual <- c("Jeff","NA","John","NA","NA")
Outcome: 1 0 1 0 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can also be done with `ifelse`:

```r
Individual <- c("Jeff","NA","John","NA","NA")
ifelse(Individual == "NA", 0L, 1L)
#> [1] 1 0 1 0 0
```

Or as suggested by Ronak with `NA`:

```r
Individual <- c("Jeff", NA, "John", NA, NA)
ifelse(is.na(Individual), 0L, 1L)
#> [1] 1 0 1 0 0
```

I consider the `ifelse` solution to be easier to read. On the other hand, Ronaks solution is a lot faster (i.e. by about a factor 10).

<sup>Created on 2021-02-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need `ifelse` since you can convert logical values to integers. Use :

```
Individual <- c("Jeff","NA","John","NA","NA")
result <- as.integer(Individual != 'NA')
result
#[1] 1 0 1 0 0
```

However, if you have actual `NA` values and not string `"NA"` we can use `is.na` to check.

```
Individual <- c("Jeff",NA,"John",NA,NA)
result <- as.integer(!is.na(Individual))
result
#[1] 1 0 1 0 0
```